# Populate Fillable Form PDF from MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

Having a problem with some VBA code I found on this site.  It is to populate a field in a PDF fillable form document from MS Access.  I adjusted the code best I could, but still getting an error.

```
Dim strTemplate, strPath, strDir, gApp, avDoc, pdDoc, jso

strPath = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\"))
strDir = Left(CurrentDb.Name, InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\"))
strDir = strDir & "Plans\" & Form_Plan_Frm!Cage & "\" & Form_Plan_Frm!UID
strTemplate = strPath & "Templates\test.pdf"

Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")

Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
If avDoc.Open(strTemplate, "") Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    jso.getField("Form1[0].Pg1[0].Topinfo[0].UIDName[0]").Value = "37555-20170517-00001-00023"
    pdDoc.Save PDSaveIncremental, "Test.pdf" 'Save changes to the PDF document
    pdDoc.Close
End If

avDoc.Close (True)

Set gApp = Nothing
Set avDoc = Nothing
Set pdDoc = Nothing
Set jso = Nothing
```

The error I am getting on the line

```
jso.getField("Form1[0].Pg1[0].fieldName[0].UIDName(0)").Value = "37555-20170517-00001-00023"
```

> "Run time error '424'; Object Required"

Below is a screenshot of what LiveCycle shows for the structure.

[image: Structure]

Comment: `jso.getField("Form1[0].Pg1[0].fieldName[0].TopInfo(0).UIDName(0)").Value` - what is `.fieldName[0]` there for?  `TopInfo` appears to come directly beneath `pg1`.

Comment: Did not see that, thanks.  Changed that and also changed the parenthesis to brackets.  But still got the same error.

Comment: Small progress getting made.  Turns out the field name is case sensitive.  so I updated it to:    "jso.getField("form1[0].pg1[0].TopInfo[0].UIDName[0]").Value = "37555-20170517-00001-00023"".  I no longer get any errors, but the field does not get the value I am trying to populate it with.

Comment: False hope maybe?...Kept working on it and now its back getting the error.  Not sure why or how to move forward.

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? This would be a lot easier in Java or .net

Comment: Not against that, just not familiar. Just needs to be done in access. Got an example?  I'm up for anything that works.

Comment: Bumping this in hopes of getting some direction on how to put java into the access code to set the fields of the pdf.  Thinking that I might have mis interpreted the comment by Joris Schellekens.  Maybe he meant to just do the whole thing in java (not possible though).