# Programmatically fill in pdf text fields

Tags: pdf

I have some pdf forms that I am trying to populate the text fields programmatically.  The program I am working with is MS Access 2013.  I have tried to fill the fields directly, but no such luck.  The pdf will be local to the Access database.

Is there a way that I could write the fields to a text file and kick off another script (powershell, javascript or whatever) to read that file and fill in the text fields?  Im not familiar with other languages, but will figure it out if it will work.

Comment: You can use VBA to push data into the form. Are you familiar with VBA?

Comment: I am.  I tried to do it with VBA inside of Access and its not working.  Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771955/populate-pdf-from-access-problems?noredirect=1#comment78643504_45771955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the fix is going to be writing to a text file from Access, opening the pdf and inside the pdf is javascript to read in that file and update the fields.  A little clunky but it is working.